# Modular .NET Core Web Application with AngularJS and WebAPI

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I want to working on the Single Page Application Based on .Net Core 2.0 with AngularJS for front-end. We have request that the application must be modular, which means that we must separate Back-end and front-end for each modules. We have been trying to find best approach for the project.

We try to use **[ASP.NET Boilerplate - Application Framework](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/)** for this approach but i don't know how to support static files such as html and JavaScript files for angular per **[modules](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Module-System)** and We cannot configured Main Web-app to lookup static files in different location (modules must separate with project files).

I cannot find **[examples](https://github.com/thangchung/awesome-dotnet-core)** for this case (Modular App Based on .NET core  and WebAPI and AngularJS,Typescript ...). Do anybody have suggestion how can we solve this problem, or do you suggest another approach or framework or sample code.

**Note: The main problem is add routing With angularJS in Modules when modules are load in  Main application start up Event**.

Comment: hey buddy, have a look at [File Providers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers)

Comment: Hi unos, thanks for your reply. the main problem is add routing With angularJS in Modules when modules are load in Main application start up Event.

Comment: you can make an Interface and implement it in every module. then in startup get implemented classes and generate a routing which gather from all projects. something like what IOCs do in multi layer projects